# $q.all jasmine returns undefined response using jasmine

Tags: angularjs, jasmine

I am facing an issue, I am writing test case for my controller.

```
 $q.all([
                staticDataService.getStaticData(viewType),
                driverService.getDrivers()
            ]).then(function (response) {
                vm.staticData = response[0];
                vm.drivers = response[1].drivers;
```

My Test case is

```
 beforeEach(inject(function ($rootScope, $q, _CONFIG_,$httpBackend, $controller) {
staticDataService = jasmine.createSpyObj('staticDataService', ['getStaticData','getDisplayRule']);
driverService = jasmine.createSpyObj('driverService',['getDrivers','setSecondaryDriverId','orderData','deleteSecondaryDriver']);
});

 staticDataService.getStaticData.and.callFake(function () {
            var d = q.defer();
            d.resolve(resultStaticData);
            return d.promise;
        });

        driverService.getDrivers.and.returnValue({ $promise: q.when(resultMakes) });
        driverUtilityService.calculateDriverAge.and.returnValue(2);

        DriversSummaryController.initialize();
        $rootScope.$apply();
```

But when I debug my test case I get response[0] and response[1] as undefined.
Please help me to rectify this issue.

Thanks.
Sajesh

Comment: is this with jasmine

Comment: yes using jasmine 2.0

Answer (score 0):

The syntax for setting up the spies is

```
spyOn(object, 'method').and.returnValue(...);
```

This concerns all statements that use `.and` method.

`$q.all` does `when` internally, so `staticDataService.getStaticData` and `driverService.getDrivers` can be mocked with their resolved values, not promises.

Comment: I am already doing this on beforeEach. driverService = jasmine.createSpyObj('driverService',['getDrivers','setSecondaryDriverId','orderData','deleteSecondaryDriver']);
            staticDataService = jasmine.createSpyObj('staticDataService', ['getStaticData','getDisplayRule']);

Comment: Then it looks fine. It looks like you haven't posted all the relevant code, the posted code doesn't contain the error which caused that. Get rid of unnecessary promises and check what's wrong with resultStaticData and resultMakes, try to recreate the issue in plunker if it won't help.